# Why does this function/constructor argument become a free implicit variable?

Tags: pattern-matching, idris, dependent-type, inspect, unification

I'm trying to implement [Agda's `inspect` idiom](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/README.Inspect.html) in Idris, as a possible workaround for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61914520/477476), however, it seems when I pattern match on the `MkReveal` constructor, the choice of `f` is lost and instead becomes a free parameter.

First, the Idris port of `inspect`:

```
%default total

data Reveal : {a : Type} -> {b : a -> Type} -> (f : (x : a) -> b x) -> (x : a) -> (y : b x) -> Type where
  MkReveal : {a : Type} -> {b : a -> Type} -> {f : (x : a) -> b x} -> {x : a} -> {y : b x} -> (f x = y) -> Reveal {b = b} f x y

inspect : {b : a -> Type} -> (f : (x : a) -> b x) -> (x : a) -> Reveal f x (f x)
inspect {b = b} f x = MkReveal {b = b} {f = f} {y = f x} Refl

applyInspect : {b : a -> Type} -> (f : (x : a) -> b x) -> (x : a) -> (y ** Reveal f x y)
applyInspect f x = (f x ** inspect f x)
```

Then how I try to use it:

```
foo : (Monad m) => m ()
foo = do
    let selected = the (Vect 2 Nat) $ pure 0
    let elems = the (Vect 9 Nat) $ pure 0

    let (((n ** xs), (k ** ys)) ** MkReveal eq) = 
            applyInspect (partition (`elem` selected)) elems
    ?wtf
```

Here, in the hole `?wtf` I would expect the type of `eq` to be               `` partition (`elem` selected) elems = ((n ** xs), (k ** ys)) ``. However, instead, a new implicitly-bound variable `f` is brought in scope:

```
f : (x : Vect (fromInteger 9) Nat) ->
    (\__pi_arg4 => ((p : Nat ** Vect p Nat), (q : Nat ** Vect q Nat))) x
eq : f elems = ((n ** xs), (k ** ys))
```

**Edited to add:** I have discovered that if I manually specify the `b` agument to `applyInspect`, I can get the desired type for `eq`:

```
    let (((n ** xs), (k ** ys)) ** MkReveal eq) = 
            applyInspect {b = \_ => (DPair Nat (\p => Vect p Nat), DPair Nat (\q => Vect q Nat))}
                (partition (`elem` selected)) elems
```

This results in

```
eq : partition (\ARG =>
                  elemBy (\meth, meth =>
                            Prelude.Nat.Nat implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method == meth
                                                                                               meth)
                         ARG
                         selected)
               elems =
     ((n ** xs), (k ** ys))
```

which is what I'd want.

So, maybe a related question could be, **how was I supposed to figure this out** (there are no yellow highlights like one you'd get in Agda for unsolved metas...), and **is there a way to tweak `Reveal` or `applyInspect`'s definitions** so that the `b` argument is correctly inferred?

Comment: FWIW, changing `inspect`/`applyInspect` to only support non-dependent `f` (i.e. changing the type of `f` to `a -> b`) doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the root of this problem is overloading: without knowing its specific type, the occurrence of `partition` is ambiguous between `Prelude.List.partition` and `Data.Vect.partition`.

Changing the code to

```
let (((n ** xs), (k ** ys)) ** MkReveal eq) = 
        applyInspect (Data.Vect.partition (`elem` selected)) elems
```

assigns the correct type to `eq`.

Also, it turns out the whole `Reveal` machinery isn't giving much, i.e. I can do everything with the simpler

```
inspect : {b : a -> Type} -> (f : (x : a) -> b x) -> (x : a) -> (y ** (f x = y))
inspect f x = (f x ** Refl)
```